# iPhone scroll bug when swiping on a textbox

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I have [a webpage](http://neptune.tandola.com/iphonebug.htm) with the following html:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style='display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100%;'>
        <div style='overflow:auto'>
            <div style='height:500px; background:green;'></div>
            <div class='container'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-sm-6'>
                        <input type='text' style='' class='form-control' placeholder='swipe here' />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style='height:500px; background:blue;'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Load it on an iPhone. Try scrolling up and down by swiping. Now try scrolling by starting a swipe at the textbox that says 'swipe here'. With me, it won't scroll when I do that. I'm using an iPhone 6S.

Is this a bug? How can I work around it?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: `Go to ...`  -> *no*. Your question must contain a reproducible problem description in the question it self. Once the problem is fixed this question will be useless in the future. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @NicoO Is it OK now?

Comment: What do you expect helpers to do with this snipped? At least show some effort and make it executable with a stack snipped. Also your "question" contains two questions 1. Is this a bug? > Well, maybe. and 2. How to work around it. Which seems too broad. You should describe what is the current behaviour and what you actually want it to do and what you tried on your own to make it so.

Comment: @Nico It is not snipped. Did you even try it?

Comment: @Nico I did describe the current behaviour (it's worth reading the question). About writing what I actually want it to do - well, since the issue is that it _won't_ scroll, most people can work out that what I want is that it _will_ scroll!

Comment: The issue is appearing on iPhone 6s and above. It seems to be caused by the `<div style='overflow:auto'>`. Remove the `overflow` and the page scrolls on swiping the textbox. Tested in safari on iPhone 6s, 6s+, 7, 8 and X. Hope this helps. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is appearing on iPhone 6s and above.

It seems to be caused by the `<div style='overflow:auto'>`. When the `overflow` is removed, the page scrolls on swiping the textbox too.

Tested in safari on iPhone 6s, 6s+, 7, 8 and X. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I awarded this the bounty. Unfortunately in my real-life webpage I need the `overflow:auto', since I'm using the technique in https://codepen.io/anthonyLukes/pen/DLBeE to have a fixed header.

Comment: I will work on a solution and get back to you. Thank you for the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

From user perspective, this is a bug.

When using bootstrap, you need to enclose the row class in a container class like the code below. The page obtains the properties to scroll left and right because of this CSS from bootstrap:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

The example below with div.container helps to give restriction to the width of the app.

```
<div style='display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100%;'>
  <div style='overflow:auto'>
    <div style='height:500px; background:green;'></div>

    <!--This container is missing to get bootstrap row to work well-->

    <div class="container">
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
          <input type='text' style='' class='form-control' placeholder='swipe here' />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style='height:500px; background:blue;'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However I added a `container` element to my example at http://neptune.tandola.com/iphonebug.htm and the issue that you can't scroll up and down, when beginning the swipe at the textbox, remains.

Comment: The text box is an input so does not scroll unless it has content to scroll. Do you have an example site that does something you want to achieve?

Comment: It actually works fine on my iPhone 5C. Both safari and chrome. No more bugs using http://neptune.tandola.com/iphonebug.htm. Try clearing the cache

Comment: So you put your finger on the textbox, and slide your finger up, and the webpage scrolls down properly?

Comment: It does work fine as you describe. Scrolls without any issue.

Comment: So I guess the issue is not on version 5C. On my 6S it doesn't scroll on Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165815/discussion-between-omukiguy-and-wezten).

Comment: I Checked on iPhone 6 Plus it works fine now. Did u fix it?

Comment: No. I guess iPhone 6S is different, but note that I reproduced the issue on the iPhone 8+ simulator on a mac.